# Jar inside Eclipse project runtime error

Tags: java, eclipse, android-emulator, jar, classpath

I am using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) as an external Jar into my Eclipse project.
The Classpath for this **external Jar** is properly set into the .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        [...]
        <classpathentry kind="lib" path="json-simple-1.1.1.jar"/>
        [...]
</classpath>
```

The Java code **compiles without any error**.

When I run the compiled code I get the following **runtime error**:

```
Could not find class 'org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser',  referenced from method [...]
```

I can't understand why, I think I am missing something but I can't figure it out.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: I am running it with Eclipse (Run menu -> Run). This is an Android project, I run it on the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make this library available in runtime, while your application is running within the emulator. To do this, put the `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` file in the `assets/` or `libs/` directory, as per [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#ApplicationProjects). It will be bundled with your application in the `.apk` file and it should be available in runtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I think checking the Jar in the "Order and Export" tab (as suggested by @Jeremy Heiler) and pulling it up on the ordered list is enough, anyway putting things in the proper folder is always a good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running it *inside Eclipse*, take a look at the classpath setting in your Run/Debug configuration. This classpath seems to be different from the normal project/compiler classpath setting in Eclipse.

Comment: I am running it inside Eclipse. This is an Android project, I set the classpath through a right click on the project, then selecting "Properties", then "Java Build Path", then "Add JARs", then locating the Jar file.

Comment: In the "Order and Export" tab, is the jar checked?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler thanks for the hint. I checked the Jar, but the emulator is still giving me the same error.